# How to Exclude Processes from Iteration in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

Is it possible to break Iterate Raster after certain set of processes ?

I have a list of Image files which I am processing using Iterate Rasters and performing aggregate and Extract Values to Points and then writing the output to a textfile.

I have three processes:

1. Aggregate
2. Extract Values to Points
3. Writing to textfile

I want to execute process 1 and 2 in Iterate, but 3 Process I don't want to perform in the Iteration.  Instead, I want to perform process 3 after all the Iteration got completed for the 1 and 2 process in the same Model.

Anybody has any idea how can I achieve this in the same model?

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use the iterations portion as a completed model, then use that model inside of another that performs the remaining operations on the output of the iteration model.  This is called a [nested model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Integrating_a_model_within_a_model/002w0000007p000000/).  Also, consider looking into Python scripting, the options for dropping into and out of iterations are much more flexible.

Comment: @ Jay Guarneri :  Thank you the way you have suggested is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links which are related to @Jay's post:

[Example of using an iterator in a model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Example_of_using_an_iterator_in_a_model/002w00000063000000/)

[Integrating a model within a model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007p000000)

Comment: -1 I was unable to find any information about how to exclude processes from iteration within this link.  Could you please expand on your comment to address the original question?

Comment: @Aaron - I agree with you but I believe this is the relevant content: "If an iterator is added to a model, all tools in the model iterate for each value in the iterator. If you do not want to run each tool in the model for each iterated value, create a [submodel/model within a model/nested model](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/002w/002w0000007p000000.htm) that contains only the iterator and add it as a model tool into the main model"